# Growing a Span<T>, assuming underlying array has enough capacity

Tags: c#

Assume we have a span which points to a sub-range of an array.

Is there any way to grow this span, assuming the initial underlying array has enough capacity to do so? (Assuming we can't use

Example:

```
int[] array = new int[]{4, 17, 0, 2, 3, 16, 1};
var span = new Span<int>(array);

var s1 = span.Slice(0, 1);
// Assume we can't use "array" directly here anymore, but only s1
var s2 = s1.Slice(0, 2); // bang! Argument of ouf range exception, even though array would have enough capacity
```

Comment: I think that would pretty much go against the philosophy of `Span<T>` and the whole idea of managed bounds-checking.

Comment: "Only s1" means you lost everything else (think of it as read-only collection or result of linq query, there is officially no way back) and only have `{ 4 }` at your hand. You are not supposed to get more items from nowhere. If you need original collection, then somewhere is architectural mistake.

Comment: Consider that `var s2 = s1.Slice(0, 2);` takes a slice of the slice, and it does re-slice the original array as you think it might do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not safely -- the Span doesn't know how large the underlying array is.

---

One **unsafe** option is to use `MemoryMarshal`:

```
var s2 = MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref MemoryMarshal.GetReference(s1), 7);
```

We use `GetReference` to get a `ref int` variable which points to the first element in the array, and pass that to `CreateSpan` with an explicit length.

**You can write to arbitrary memory if you get the length wrong, so be careful!**

---

There might be a way to try and get the original array back out of the `Span`, and then query its length, but I can't find one. `MemoryMarshal.TryGetArray` takes a `Memory`, not a `Span`.